# React Semantic Ui dropdown set dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am using react-semantic-ui

Here is the scenario:

I have two (2) dropdowns with placeholders, I am setting the 2nd Dropdown's option dynamically when I choose from the 1st dropdown. Then I would choose an item from the 2nd dropdown.

Then, If I changed the value of the 1st dropdown, it should change the values of the 2nd dropdown again, I have no problems with that but I want to set the placeholder back again

Summary: First I chose an item from the 1st dropdown, that sets the options of the 2nd dropdown. Then I choose an item from the 2nd dropdown, then I choose AGAIN from the 1st dropdown and that resets the options of the 2nd dropdown but that placeholder is not showing anymore.

[image: Here it is]